# Ternary error correction codes

Tags: coding-theory

Let`s define ternary  ECC  as a code that its codewords can be defined by $ \{ xyz f(y,z) f(x,z) f(x,y) | x,y,z \in \{0,1\}^m \} $ for some function $f$. $f$ returns bitstring of constant length.

Are there any known good error correction codes that are ternary?

Such a family of LDPC codes would be best.

Is there a reason it won't be good(in terms of distance, rate)?

It might be useful in a construction I have. I just wanted to make sure it is not known already before I dive in.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please give more details if you want appropriate answers.

Comment: I improved this, but let me know what is unclear, if it is still unclear.

Comment: Does $xy$ means the concatenation of $x$ and $y$? Please give an example for such codes and the function $f$

Comment: $x,y$ are by definition $m$-tuples of words. So "concatenation" does  not make sense.

Comment: x, y, z are bitstrings of length m. Concatenation makes sense.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but the choice of "ternary" seems unfortunate-- there's a already a whole literature on ternary ECCs, where "ternary" means "base-3".  Your codes are binary with special structure.

Comment: $x. y, z$ were not bitstrings a little while ago.

Comment: The function $f$ is not defined. I guess it is any function of two variables where the input is a pair of binary words of length $m$ and the output is a binary word of length $m$. So the code words have lengths $6m$, the first half of a word is an arbitrary binary word of length $3m$ and the second half depends on $f$ and is for error checking. Then everything depends on $f$. For example if $f$ is a constant function, then the second halfs of the code words are the same and the usefulness of this code is doubtful. In general, using so many bits for error correcting seems excessive.

Comment: @Mark, I don't know what exactly OP has in mind for $f$, but nothing OP has written leads me to think its output is meant to be of length $m$. Maybe it's some kind of parity check, and its output is a single bit.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to update my comment saying it was GF field not a long time ago by mistake. Had a timeout.  The function f returns bitstring. Sorry for that.

Comment: OK, but the *length* of that bitstring seems to be important. That is, the answer to your question seems to depend on just how long that bitstring is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if the function $f$ has range $GF(2)^m$, represented by $GF(2^m)$ if convenient, it has rate 1/2. Such a function can really control symbol ($GF(2^m)$ ) not bit errors so it is a code over $GF(2^m)$ of length $n=6$ and rate 1/2 (dimension 3). If the code is MDS [best possible] it has symbol distance at most $n-k+1=6-3+1,$ 4, so could correct double symbol errors.

A Reed-Solomon code would achieve this, and is the optimal such code. But we do need $2^m+1\geq n=6,$ (since Reed Solomon codes are essentially evaluation codes) so $m$ would have to be at least 3.

**Edit:** If $f$ maps into $GF(2)$ as suggested by Gerry Myerson, then this is a single error correcting code with $n=3m+3$ and $3$ parity checks. If $3m+3=2^n-1,$ then a Hamming code will do, and no fancy $f$ could do better.